# Thoughts on Post-Structuralism and Post-Modernist theory?

Tags: argumentation, society, art

I'm curious as to what you all think about post-modernist and post-structuralist methods of analysis, as in the past year, these words have been thrown a lot in the academic and political spheres. Do you think that this method of analysis will be ultimately good for society and academics?

Also, perhaps you guys can clarify the definition of post-modernism. As I see it, in simplest terms it is the rejection that something can be assessed objectively and can only be assessed through different social and cultural lenses. Is this a correct definition?

I personally think that while this way of thinking has a certain degree of merit, it will ultimately result in a degradation of culture since it supports the idea that the quality of something (Art, literature, music, poetry etc.) can only be  subjectively assessed, therefore resulting in the creation things that have poorer quality.

Comment: You can see [many posts](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search?q=post-modernism) on post-modernism on this site.

Comment: But [Relativism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/relativism/) has a significant place in philosophy and we can link it back also to [Ancient Skepticism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/skepticism-ancient/).

Comment: Thus, the idea that "quality in Art, literature, etc. can only be subjectively assesses" has a strong philosophical support.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I certainly agree that the idea that art can be subjectively assessed has merit, I think that this idea can be taken too far and results in a complete lack of objective quality. I think that, among other things, this subjectivity is the reason that the great music of yesteryear, for example, is not being created today.